# Unable to Install Firefox OS Simulator on Firefox WebIDE in Mac OS Sierra Version - 10.12

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk, macos-sierra, firefox-os

I am trying to install Firefox OS Simulator in Firefox WebIDE. Always getting Operation failed: Download failed error. Intially I tried with FirefoxDeveloperEdition 58.0 and got not compitable for all available simulators. Later I tried with Firefox 57.0 got same not compitable error. Now I am tring with Firefox 45.0.1 getting error as Operation failed: Download failed error.

Not able to figure out where the issue reside, whether its with Firefox or Mac OS?

Please help me out. Attached Screen shots.

[image: Firefox 45.0.1]

[image: FirefoxDeveloperEdition 58.0 and Firefox 57.0]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installing Firefox 43 is sorted out the issue. Its available in mozilla archives.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried to install **Firefox OS 2.6 simulator** with **Firefox 53.0.2**, and it can work as expected.

(Note: my MacOS version is still El Capitan)